# Menu takes two clicks to open after closing from the body

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

If I open the menu and then close it by clicking anywhere on the body I have to click twice to open it again. What am I doing wrong? Below is my code.

```
 closeDropdownMenu() {
   if (document.querySelector('.mdc-simple-menu--open')) {
    document.querySelector('.mdc-simple-menu').classList.remove('mdc-simple-menu--open');
   }
 }

initializeDropDownMenu() {

  const mdmMenuEl = document.querySelector('.js-dropdown-menu');

  if (!mdmMenuEl) return;

  const mdcMenu = new MDCSimpleMenu(mdmMenuEl);
  const menuToggleEL = document.querySelector('.js-dropdown-toggle');

  menuToggleEL.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    mdcMenu.open = !mdcMenu.open;

  });
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () =>
    this.closeDropdownMenu()
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's because when you close the menu, you don't set `mdcMenu.open` to `false` and so the next click still thinks `mdcMenu.open === true`, which sets it to `false` (and no menu opens). But then one more click sets the `false` to `true` and then the menu opens.

Change the `body.click` code to:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => {
  mdcMenu.open = false;
  this.closeDropdownMenu();
});
```